# Run MySQL Server in Python

Tags: python, mysql

So I've been looking all over the internet and only found resources/tutorials on how to connect to a MySQL server but my question is, how do you host a MySQL server both on Windows & Linux?

Comment: What specifically are you asking here?

Comment: Running an MYSQL server is a lot different than connection. Try looking my setting up MySQL. If you have XAMP of WAMP then you should have MySQL running on its own. Check port 3306

Comment: I strongly recommend using `docker`. [docker mysql image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) There even is a python docker library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you are asking but if the question is how to run a database for python independent of the OS, consider using [sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/about.html).

From the link (emphasis mine)

> SQLite is an embedded SQL database engine. **Unlike most other SQL
>   databases, SQLite does not have a separate server process.** SQLite
>   reads and writes directly to ordinary disk files. A complete SQL
>   database with multiple tables, indices, triggers, and views, is
>   contained in a single disk file. The database file format is
>   cross-platform - you can freely copy a database between 32-bit and
>   64-bit systems or between big-endian and little-endian architectures.
>   These features make SQLite a popular choice as an Application File
>   Format. Think of SQLite not as a replacement for Oracle but as a
>   replacement for fopen().

So it allows you to use a database from your python code without the hassle of running a server or setting something up locally.

Note that sqlite can also be stored in-memory if you want to avoid writing to disk.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a very specific reason to *start* the server from Python, I.e. you want to be able to programmatically do stuff you wouldn't do from the command line, I think the best you could do is to [install](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) an instance of Mysql server in your local machine, run it and then, you'll be able to connect to it from Python.

Bear in mind that your local installation of Mysql will be running on `localhost` (`127.0.0.1`)

Comment: That's not what I asked, the reason is to package a MySQL server with compiled Python Applications which can be run alongside the application and used for data storage.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I misunderstood your question, but to the question “how do you host a MySQL server both on Windows & Linux?“ my answer is ok, you can host them both on Linux and Windows. No need to downvote :)

Comment: Again, not what I asked. The question is how to do it in Python.